# Linear Algebra question on diagonlization Please check my work

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

My first question is that is a basis for each eigenspace the same thing as a corresponding eigenvector for an eigenspace?

Could someone tell me if im doing this correctly?

I have the matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix}
4 & 3 & 3\\
-9 & -8 & -9\\
3 & 3 & 4\\
\end{bmatrix}$

I found out that the characteristic polynomial is $-(\lambda-1)^2(\lambda+2)$

So the eigenvalues are -2 and 1.

I solved for the the eigenvector for $\lambda=-2$ and I got the eigenvector to be $\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
-3 \\
1\\
\end{bmatrix}$

When I solve for $\lambda=1$, I get $\begin{bmatrix}
-1 \\
1 \\
0\\
\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}
-1 \\
0 \\
1\\
\end{bmatrix}$ as my basis.

So from this is my $P=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & -1\\
-3 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}$ and my $D=\begin{bmatrix}
-2 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}$?

And lastly,how does the negative sign in my characteristic polynomial affect my answer?

Could you please check my work, I feel like I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Are you sure you typed $A$ correctly?

Comment: yea it is typed correctly. I was given the characteristic polynomial

Comment: The characteristic polynomial is wrong which makes it even weirder that you were able to find eigenvectors.

Comment: sorry I added a negative sign piece of dust on my paper :/

Comment: last 3 on row 1 is positive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The negative sign as no bearing on your answer because you're interested in the roots of the polynomial and $-(\lambda-1)^2(\lambda+2)=0\iff (\lambda-1)^2(\lambda+2)=0$.

You can check what you did yourself by computing $P^{-1}AP$.

In fact
$$\begin{align}P^{-1}AP &=\begin{bmatrix} -1& -1 &-1\\ -3 & -2 & -3\\ 1 & 1 & 2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 4 & 3 & 3\\ -9 & -8 & -9\\ 3 & 3 & 4\end{bmatrix}P\\
&=\begin{bmatrix} 2& 2 & 2\\ -3 & -2 & -3\\ 1 & 1 & 2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 & -1\\ -3 & 1 & 0\\ 1 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}=D.\end{align}$$

Comment: Ok nice, looks like im correct XD